# Finding general solutions of a differential equations, with specific solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

so I'm not a native english speaker, so bear with me.

Let there be an equation $y'+p(x)y=q(x)$.

$y_1=4e^{-2x}+2x-1$ and $y_2=2x-1$ are "private solutions" or "specific solutions" - not sure of the English term.

And the questions is - finding the general solution.

How do I solve this?

Thank you, 
 Vova

Comment: the solutions $y_1, y_2$ are particular solutions, meaning they satisfy the differential equation but not any ether constraints like initial or boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you have is linear, so it follows that $y=e^{-2x}$ is a solution to the homogeneous problem $y'+p(x)y=0$ and the general solution is of the form $y=2x-1+Ce^{-2x}$.

Since $y_1,y_2$ satisfy the non-homogeneous problem, it follows that $y_1-y_2=4e^{-2x}$ solves the homogeneous problem $Ly=0$ by linearity of the differential operator $L=d/dx+p(x)\operatorname{Id}$ as $L[y_1-y_2]=L[y_1]-L[y_2]=q(x)-q(x)=0$. That $y=Ce^{-2x}$ is the general solution to the homogeneous problem follows readily.

Comment: Can you please explain why is $y=e^{-2x}$ the solution to that homogeneous problem?

Comment: @Vova, write the two equations ${Py_1}^' + py_1 = q$ and ${y_2}^' + py_2 = q.$ now subtract the second from the first. you find $(y_1-y_2)^' + p(y_1-y_2) = 0$ that should tell you what $p$ is.